# Reading an XML webpage into R and storing as a data frame object when the page is not recognised as an XML page

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to read in the following data from this XML page [here](https://catsalut.gencat.cat/web/.content/xml/out.xml). However, I cannot seem to correctly store the data.

The data has 7 `region nom_reg` and each of these has a differing number of `comarcas`, inside each `comarcas` there is a differing number of `municipis`. I would like to store this data in lists.

Data and my progress/attempt:

```
library(XML)
genCat <- "http://catsalut.gencat.cat/web/.content/xml/out.xml"
#xmlParse(genCat)
#xmlToDataFrame(genCat)

library(dplyr)
library(xml2)
data <- read_xml(genCat)
parsedData <- xmlParse(data)

#d2 <- xmlInternalTreeParse(data)
d3 <- xmlRoot(parsedData)
xmlName(d3[['regio']][['comarca']][['municipi']])

xmlValue(d3[['regio']][['comarca']][['municipi']])
#xml_attr(d3[['regio']][['comarca']][['municipi']])

xpathSApply(d3, "/mapa_sanitari/regio/comarca", xmlValue)

d4 <- xpathSApply(d3, "/mapa_sanitari/regio/comarca/municipi")

dx <- xpathSApply(d3, "/mapa_sanitari")
dx <- xpathSApply(d3, "/mapa_sanitari/regio")
dx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(xml2)
librart(magrittr) #for pipe operator
url <- "http://catsalut.gencat.cat/web/.content/xml/out.xml"
doc <- xml2::read_xml(url)
#get the minicipi nodes
mun.nodes <- xml2::xml_find_all(doc, ".//municipi")
#build data.frame
df <- data.frame(
  nom.mu  = mun.nodes %>% xml_attr("nom_mu"),
  cod_mu  = mun.nodes %>% xml_attr("cod_mu"),
  nom_com = xml2::xml_find_first(mun.nodes, xpath = ".//ancestor::comarca") %>% xml_attr("nom_com"),
  cod_com = xml2::xml_find_first(mun.nodes, xpath = ".//ancestor::comarca") %>% xml_attr("cod_com"),
  nom_reg = xml2::xml_find_first(mun.nodes, xpath = ".//ancestor::regio") %>% xml_attr("nom_reg"),
  cod_reg = xml2::xml_find_first(mun.nodes, xpath = ".//ancestor::regio") %>% xml_attr("cod_reg"))
# > head(df)
#          nom.mu  cod_mu    nom_com cod_com            nom_reg cod_reg
# 1   Alàs I Cerc 2500500 Alt Urgell      04 Alt Pirineu i Aran      71
# 2      Arsèguel 2503200 Alt Urgell      04 Alt Pirineu i Aran      71
# 3      Bassella 2504400 Alt Urgell      04 Alt Pirineu i Aran      71
# 4          Cabó 2506100 Alt Urgell      04 Alt Pirineu i Aran      71
# 5          Cava 2507100 Alt Urgell      04 Alt Pirineu i Aran      71
# 6 Coll De Nargó 2507700 Alt Urgell      04 Alt Pirineu i Aran      71
```